# The Diamond of Columbus

Tags: no-computers, tiling, polyomino

There are up to flipping / rotation 12 distinct pentominoes.

Can you fit them without overlap in the white area?

[image]

Comment: I think I've done this pattern before, but full diamond with hole in center.

Comment: @DanielMathias Does that even have a solution?

Comment: I guess not, but I do recall making an effort.

Comment: The complete diamond with central hole has no solutions. In fact there are 8 solutions with the hole 'as asked', and only a further two which both have the hole diagonally adjacent to that position. No other positions for the hole are possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a bit of Tinkering, this is the first solution I found.

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

[@DanielMathias found an answer first](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122985/18250), but this also fits:

> [image]
>
> Found by playing around with the corners and then filling in the middle

Turns out, after a bit of research there are actually 8 solutions, as seen [here](https://puzzler.sourceforge.net/solutions/ominoes/pentominoes-diamond.txt):

> Using the following letters to represent the pentominoes:
>
>  [image]
>
> The 8 solutions are:
>
>         `N N N`
>       `Y U U N N`
>     `Y Y U L L L L`
>   `F F Y U U Z Z L X`
> `F F T Y V V V Z X X X`
>   `F T T T I V Z Z X`
>     `T P P I V W W`
>       `P P I W W`
>         `P I W`
>           `I`
>
>         `N N N`
>       `T T T N N`
>     `U U T V V V Z`
>   `F F U T V Z Z Z X`
> `F F U U I V Z Y X X X`
>   `F P P I Y Y Y Y X`
>     `P P I L L W W`
>       `P I L W W`
>         `I L W`
>           `L`
>
>         `N N N`
>       `T T T N N`
>     `U U T V V V Z`
>   `F F U T V Z Z Z X`
> `F F U U I V Z Y X X X`
>   `F P P I Y Y Y Y X`
>     `P P I L L L L`
>       `P I L W W`
>         `I W W`
>           `W`
>
>         `N N N`
>       `T T T N N`
>     `P P T L V V V`
>   `P P P T L V U U X`
> `I I I I I L V U X X X`
>   `W W Z Z L L U U X`
>     `W W Z Y Y Y Y`
>       `W Z Z F Y`
>         `F F F`
>           `F`
>
>         `N N N`
>       `T T T N N`
>     `P P T L L L L`
>   `P P P T V V V L X`
> `I I I I I Z Z V X X X`
>   `Y Y Y Y Z U V U X`
>     `Y F Z Z U U U`
>       `F F F W W`
>         `F W W`
>           `W`
>
>         `N N N`
>       `T T T N N`
>     `Z Z T L V V V`
>   `P P Z T L V U U X`
> `P P P Z Z L V U X X X`
>   `Y Y Y Y L L U U X`
>     `Y F I I I I I`
>       `F F F W W`
>         `F W W`
>           `W`
>
>         `N N N`
>       `N N Z Z W`
>     `V V V L Z W W`
>   `X U U V L Z Z W W`
> `X X X U V L I I I I I`
>   `X U U L L T P P P`
>     `Y Y Y Y T P P`
>       `Y F T T T`
>         `F F F`
>           `F`
>
>         `N N N`
>       `T T T N N`
>     `P P T L V V V`
>   `P P P T L V U U X`
> `Y Y Y Y Z L V U X X X`
>   `Y Z Z Z L L U U X`
>     `Z F I I I I I`
>       `F F F W W`
>         `F W W`
>           `W`

Comment: You did this by hand?

Comment: Are there solutions to the diamond with hole in center?

Comment: @msh210 the first one by hand yes, then was curious to see how many solutions and found the website

Comment: @DanielMathias no solutions apparently